# Audio Libraries Written in Go?

Tags: c++, audio, go

Are there any native-Go audio libraries out there? Specifically, I would like to read the peaks from an audio file in order to construct a waveform. Alternatively I know I could use something like SWIG to bind with an established C++ audio library. However, if a Go library is available, I would like to use that. It would be cleaner, and I wouldn't need to learn how to use SWIG while I'm learning how to use the library.

Comment: If you just use a C library you can use cgo (http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/), no need to mess with SWIG …

Comment: @filmor - Thanks! Do you know of any good pure-C audio libraries? I was thinking of going down this route, but I've heard that a lot of audio libraries end up having a good amount of C++ in them, which is what led me to SWIG.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of "Music" libraries written in go:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Projects#music

And here is a list of "Graphics and Audio" libraries written in go:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Projects#graphics-and-audio

That page doesn't distinguish between pure go and code linked to c libraries. I'm guessing most projects will link to existing libraries as mentioned in a previous comment.